# MVC Alternative routing is failing with optional parameter

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes

I am trying to implement alternative routing in my **MVC 5** web app.

I have the controller code:

```
namespace MyMvcProject.Web.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("account")]
    public class AccountController : Controller {


        [Route("{param}")]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index(string param = null) {

...
```

which works great when hitting the url: `http://example.com/account/testparam`.
However, I would like to be able to have the value `param` as an optional parameter.

I have tried changing `[Route("{param}")]` to `[Route("{param}*")]` but then the `Index()` method is never entered. I have also tried changing it to `[Route("{param:string=Test}")]` but I get a routing runtime error with the term `string`.

My `RoutConfig.cs` contains:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{param}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", param = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could force `Index()` to have an optional parameter using this alternative routing syntax? It's quite useful in other parts of my app, so I'd like to keep the `RoutePrefix` and `Route` decorators.

**UPDATE**

I'm still trying to figure this out, so I changed my route decorator to `[Route("{param:int=0}")]` and my constructor to `public ActionResult Index(int id)` and it works as expected (i.e., `http://example.com/account` behaves as if `http://example.com/account/0` was entered. This is exactly what I want, only using `string` datatypes.

When I change the decorator to: `[Route("{id:string=\"\"}")]` and the constructor to `public ActionResult Index(string id)` and I see the runtime error:

> The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: 'string'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Attribute%20routing%20in%20Web%20API). I need to make `param` nullable using `?`.

```
[Route("{param?}")]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index(string param = null) {
   ...
}
```

Hopefully this will help someone in the future. 
Not many references that I could find on the topic.

Answer (score 6):

**@Brett's** answer is great: adding `?` to the parameter in the Route attribute and then providing a default value in the Action signature allows that parameter to be optional.

And here's an excellent article from Mike Wasson on [Attribute Routing in Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), which includes a piece on optional parameters.

Mike also talks about applying multiple constraints, and says:

> You can apply multiple constraints to a parameter, separated by a colon.
>
> ```
>   [Route("users/{id:int:min(1)}")]
>   public User GetUserById(int id) { ... }
> ```

which also works great...until you want multiple constraints **and** an optional parameter.

As we know, applying `?` allows the parameter to be optional. So taking the above example, one might assume that

```
[Route("users/{id:int?:min(1)}")]
public User GetUserById(int id = 1) { ... }
```

constrains the `id` parameter to be integers greater than 0, or empty (in which case the default of 1 is used). In reality, we get the error message:

> The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: 'int?'.

It turns out that the **order of the constraints** matters! Simply putting the optional constraint `?` *after* all other constraints gives the intended behavior

```
[Route("users/{id:min(1):int?}")]
public User GetUserById(int id = 1) { ... }
```

This works for more than 2 constraints as well, e.g.

```
[Route("users/{id:min(1):max(10):int?}")]
public User GetUserById(int id = 1) { ... }
```

Comment: Helpful tip about the order.